# Ban command on message discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='sk?')

token = ""

@client.event
async def on_message():
    if 'WORD' in message.content:
        await member.ban(reason = WORD)

client.run(token)
```

I get the error "takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given" and I don't know what is wrong with my code.

I tried adding `on_message(member):` and `member = message.author()` above `if 'WORD' in message.content:`

I have no idea what to do or what I did wrong.

It also says that for all messages which is really annoying.

Comment: Where does the `message` in `message.content` come from?

Answer (score 0):

`on_message` takes the message argument, also `member` should be `message.author`

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "WORD" in message.content:
        await message.author.ban(reason="WORD")

    # Remember to add `process_commands`
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

You should also add `process_commands` at the end of the event so commands work